# Nesting image in columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

this is my first post ever. Just started with web dev. 
Below you see the image what I've written in Bootstrap, the second image is what I want to have.

I hope I post this correct. Please give me also feedback on how to post this problems. Thanks a lot!!!

[What I have now developed in Bootstrap.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqodA.png)

[This is what I want to have, to add a GIF/PNG on top the 3 rows on the right...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MZ13.png)

```html
<div class="container-fixed">
        <div class="row row-titles">
            <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-sm-push-7">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h1 style="color: #F5A623;"><strong>Onafhankelijk zelfzorgplatform</strong></h1>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row row-content">
            <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-sm-push-7">
                <p style="padding:0px;"></p>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="header-blue"><i class="em em-dart"></i> ZOEK UW AANDOENING.</h4>
                        <p>Lees de door onze artsen geverifierde informatie over uw (vermoedelijke) aandoening in ons uitgebreid dossier bestand en bekijk alle geregistreerde zelfzorg- producten bij uw aandoening.</p>
                        <p style="padding:10px;"></p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row row-content grey-body">
                <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-sm-push-7">
                    <p style="padding:10px;"></p>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="header-blue"><i class="em em-mag_right"></i> BEKIJK DE PRODUCTEN.</h4>
                        <p>We hebben honderden producten in onze database met volledige informatie m.b.t. de inhoud, minimum leeftijd, gebruiksadvies en contact gegevens.</p>
                        <p style="padding:10px;"></p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
         <div class="row row-content blue-body">
                <div class ="col-xs=12 col-sm-5 col-sm-push-7">
                    <p style="padding:10px;"></p>
                    <div class="blue-body">
                        <h4> <i class="em em-star2"></i> ONAFHANKELIJKE REVIEWS.</h4>
                        <p>Alle producten staan onder hun geregistreerde aandoening en worden gerankschikt op basis van gebruiks ervaring van andere. Zo kunt u een zorgvuldige keuze maken.</p>
                        <p style="padding:10px;"></p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nesting within your `row-content` to create a 7-unit col on the left, and 5-unit col to the right. The 5-unit col on the right will contain full columns with your existing 3 rows. Do this instead of pushing the cols over 7 units.

```
<div class="row row-content">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7">
            <img src=".." class="img-responsive center-block">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
            <div class="row row-content grey-body">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    ..
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row-content blue-body">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    ..
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row-content blue-body">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    ..
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/ztjbmIY6G2

Comment: It's almost working. Now the blue and grey bar are also 5 columns wide and not on the whole page....

Comment: Ok I see you want the image to float over those rows. One way is to use an `absolute` position on the image like this: http://codeply.com/go/jMNZU2yGe1

Comment: Awesome, it's partly working. Now when I resize my screen to "bigger" it's overlapping everyting also the footer. And when I get to size XS it HUGE compared to the other parts. Thanks anyways appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Yeah you will need to tweak the CSS but this should get you started. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me a hint what to tweak? Should I give the img padding in order to position it right....